# Get first few elements in a list while keeping others in memory while reading a serialized file

Tags: java, serialization, indexing

Suppose I have a list object which has 100 elements which have been serialized into the disk using writeObject().
Now can anyone please tell me what should I do to read only the first ten elements in the list while keeping all the others in the disk. As per my knowledge readObject() reads the entire list into memory. So is there any work around to it.
I want to use it in SPIMI implementation of indexing in information retieval.

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: I don't think it is possible but I prefer letting more experienced people tell you.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to do is serialize objects in the list in sequence to the disk. If you do that you can get the first few and stop reading. Avoid serializing the whole list.

Comment: An upvote for being faster with exactly my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is the idea itself or the initial design of your storing program . There is no way ( not that i know of ) that you would be able to do what you are asking about, in fact you answered it yourself , readObject() reads the whole object and returns it as Object wich you will later cast to List .

So i suggest you you change the way you store in the first place , like serializing each object on its own ... or maybe consider using a database, though it might be an overkill for just 100 elements  ,also 100 isn't a really big number for PC anymore , if the elements aren't that big of a data structure, then there is no point really .